# How would I parse a large TSV file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing, d3.js

I'm extremely new to Node and JS. I have a large TSV file (1.5gb) that I need to read in and parse into either an array or JSON object. How would I go about doing that? I don't get an error when I try the code below but it doesn't even enter into it.

```
var d3 = require("d3-dsv");

d3.tsvParse("amazon_reviews_us_Mobile_Apps_v1_00.tsv", function(error, data) 
{
    var sum = 0;
    data.forEach(function(d) 
    {
        d.helpful_votes += d.helpful_votes;
        sum += d.helpful_votes;
    });
    console.log("Total Helpful Votes: " + sum);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two problems: it should be `d3.tsv`, not `d3.tsvParse`, which works only with *strings*. Also, D3 v5 and above uses Fetch API, meaning it should be `d3.tsv(url).then(etc...)`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have tried both of these. `d3.tsv` gives me function does not exist and `d3.tsv(url).then` gives me fetch is undefined, even when I installed the d3-fetch module.

Comment: What's your D3 version?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado 2.0.0. I installed it by using `npm install d3-dsv`

Comment: Are you sure? This is 8 years old!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's what it says in my package.json and on the npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-dsv

Comment: That's the `d3-dsv` version, which is the newer one, I thought you were talking about the D3 version, sorry for my mistake. So, as I said, you need `d3.tsv`, not `d3.tsvParse`, which only works with strings. You'll find `d3.tsv` in the `d3-fetch` module, not in the `d3-dsv`. I see that you said that you already installed `d3-fetch`, so that's a mystery to me. Are you using Internet Explorer by any chance? What happens if you type `window.fetch` in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a module that provides a streaming parser for a TSV file, meaning that it doesn't load the whole file into memory. You can use readline if your parser is synchronous:

```js
const {createInterface} = require("rl");
const {createReadStream} = require("fs");

createInterface({input: createReadStream("amazon_reviews_us_Mobile_Apps_v1_00.tsv")})
   .on('line', (data) => doSomethingWith(data.split("\t")))
   .on('end', () => doSomethingWhenDone())
```

You wrote that you want to parse that file and change it to an array or object of some sort. You'll still need to be looking at your memory, but you could use my [`scramjet`](https://scramjet.org/) which will allow you to transform the data anyway you like:

```js
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");
const {createReadStream, createWriteStream} = require("fs");

StringStream.from(createReadStream("amazon_reviews_us_Mobile_Apps_v1_00.tsv"))
    // read the file
    .CSVParse({delimiter: "\t"})
    // parse as csv
    .map((entry) => doSomething(entry))
        // whatever you return here it will be changed
        // this can be asynchronous too, so you can do requests...
    .toJSONArray()
    .pipe(createWriteStream("somefile.json"))
```

Let me know what are you trying to achieve besides counting. I'll edit the answer.

BTW, for just counting votes the solution by @hugo-elhaj-lahsen is also good, I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Use `d3.tsv` with the promise-based API. Since your file is very large, one optimisation we can do is instead of doing a for-each on each element after they get parsed by D3, use [the loop done at parsing time](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv) via the **initialization function**:

```
var d3 = require("d3-dsv");

var sum = 0

d3.tsvParse("amazon_reviews_us_Mobile_Apps_v1_00.tsv", data => {
  sum += d.helpful_votes;
  return d // Since this is the parser, need to return the parsed object at the end
}).then(data => {
  console.log("Total helpful votes", sum)
})
```